# Flutter Client Side Cryptography

Tags: encryption, dart, flutter, dart-pub, tink

How can I hash and return an input in the easiest possible way on a Flutter mobile app? I want the digital signature to be returned client side. Please I seem to be dead ended here.

Comment: Please add a minimal code example ti illustrate your issue

Answer (score 0):

This is old and somewhat poorly asked, but...

I wrote a package that solves your issue. It's called steel_crypt, and it provides minimal-pain hashing in dart 2.

https://pub.dev/packages/steel_crypt

You could hash, for example, by:

```
var hasher = HashCrypt("SHA-3/512"); //generate SHA-3/512 hasher
String hash = hasher.hash("somedatahere"); //gives hash
bool check = hasher.checkhash("somedatahere", hash); //gives whether given hashed text == given plaintext
```